# res.sendFile() shows my html, but doesn't render react components

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I am making my first MERN site. I am getting a little stuck when I try to connect the react frontend, to the express backend.

I am pretty much done with my frontend and can navigate my pages there. My problems come when I try to go to pages from my server.js.

I have made my app.get("*", ...) to just test it and send visitors back to my homepage if they search for anything. When I go to something like localhost:3000/qwert, it does show my index.html, where I put an h1, but it doesn't show the react component I expected.

I am running my server and client on port 3000 and 5000 using concurrently.

Can anybody help me out?

Here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Here is my server.js

[image: Server.js]

And here is my index.html, index.js and app.js:

[image: Index.html]

[image: Index.js]

[image: App.jsx]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your route for Homepage component:

```
<Route exact path="/*" component={() => <Homepage />} />
```

Then all url's, except "/blog, /Cv/, /portfolio" will render Homepage component.

Comment: That didn't change my server (localhost:5000) and on my client (localhost:3000) it just started showing both my homepage and the other pages when I went to them I'm afraid

Comment: add "/" to path in your get method.